HDF Error when reading a NetCDF file as part of tests
My code saves and analyzes data in NetCDF4 format. I have no problem whatsoever with the analysis.
However, when I run unit tests in tox I get a ton of HDF and OS errors, e.g.:
https://github.com/StingraySoftware/HENDRICS/actions/runs/9580442835/job/26417155244?pr=164
I could reproduce this when running tox -e py311-test-alldeps, but only on Linux. On Mac OS (M1) the same tox command works with no issue, and if I run the tests with pytest on a fresh conda environment with the same software versions (in particular, the same necdf4, h5py, and numpy versions) of the tox environment, it works in all architectures. Apparently, I can only reproduce the issue while running with tox on Linux. This make debugging a lot more difficult.
Based on an old question, I tried to set HDF5_USE_FILE_LOCKING=FALSE in the setenv section of tox.ini, to no avail.

I'm encountering the same error, also only for tests that I run via nox on Linux systems. After some sleuthing within a Linux box the guilty culprit appears to be release 1.7.1 of the python netcdf4 library. I haven't dug deeper to identify the cause but you should be able to resolve this by pinning netcdf4<1.7.1 in the interim.

Thanks! The workaround worked! I used netcdf4!=1.7.1, hoping they will solve the problem before the next release.

Also, I opened an issue in the NetCDF repo: https://github.com/Unidata/netcdf4-python/issues/1343
